# CorePlot CPT Color Apply Not All Color RGB Values

Tags: ios, core-plot, rgb

I am Working Core plot BarChart Apply the Bars Colors with RGB Does not Work..!

It is Working Only Major Colors like Red,Green,Blue,White,Purple..!

I am Try to apply Orange not applying.any one help me...!

```
[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:255 green:163 blue:0 alpha:1]
```

It's Orange RGB Color Value.But, apply only Yellow Color....!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Components are floats from 0 - 1, do this:

```
[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:255.0f/255.0f green:163.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
```